# Saving HTML Form Data into XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, save, export

I am working on developing a form where an admin will use. The form data will then be used to update values of variables I plan on using throughout the website. None of these values are security-sensitive, so that shouldn't be an issue.

So, basically, my only problem right now is how do I get the form the write my data to the XML file (which will be read later to update variable values).

Here is the form code:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="handler_NAME.js></script>

<div align="center">

    <span style="font-size:60px";>

        <u>Update Page<br></u>
        PAGE TO BE UPDATED<br>

    </span>

<form method="post" action="UpdateInfo_NAME.php">
    <span style="font-size:30px;">

        <u>FIELD1<input type="number" name="name1" value="total"><br>
        FIELD2<input type="number" name="name2" value="total"><br>
        FIELD3<input type="number" name="name3" value="total"><br>
        FIELD4<input type="number" name="name4" value="total"><br>
        FIELD5<input type="number" name="name5" value="total"><br>
        FIELD6<input type="number" name="name6" value="total"><br>
        FIELD7<input type="number" name="name7" value="total"><br>
        FIELD8<input type="number" name="name8" value="total"><br></u>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form></html>
```

NOTE: the handler is currently empty. I assume I am going to need to use jQUERY to make this as clean as possible, so I also added the library (line 3). If I did anything wrong, please just tear me apart lol, I'm a noob programmer so I have to learn.

Any help is appreciated, TIA!!!

**EDIT:**
It would work best for me if the XML would be overwritten each time a user saves the data. I'm not sure if this is much harder, I suppose that is for you to tell me :P

I am working off a server, and all files are PHP's. Sorry that I didn't specify this originally haha

Comment: Are you using anything on the server side?  PHP, ASPX, JSP, etc.

Comment: You're going to need a server side language to write the file with.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify. Everything is based in PHP. OP has been edited to show this.

Comment: It was specified _action="UpdateInfo_NAME.php"_ ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try to use **SimpleXML**. Follow [This tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html) that explain very well how it works and how to use it.

Just some example about how to start with **SimpleXML**

```
<?php 

try 
{ 
    /*** a new dom object ***/ 
    $dom = new domDocument; 

    /*** make the output tidy ***/ 
    $dom->formatOutput = true; 

    /*** create the root element ***/ 
    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "user" )); 

    /*** create the simple xml element ***/ 
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 

    /*** add a firstname element ***/ 
    $sxe->addChild("firstname", "John"); 

    /*** add a surname element ***/ 
    $sxe->addChild("surname", "Brady"); 

    /*** echo the xml ***/ 
    echo $sxe->asXML(); 
} 
catch( Exception $e ) 
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I get the following error when I attempt to use this code:      Fatal error: Class 'DomDocument' not found in -DIRECTORY- on line 4

Comment: I edited my answer, try simpleXL instead, easier to use

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it :) if my rep was high enough I'd up your answer lol.

Comment: It pops up the same error, but on line 6 :/ I think the issue may be that my sever admin hasn't allowed php to xml support (I have looked into the error message online and found that multiple people have said stuff like this). I may have to figure out another way to accomplish my goal, then.

Comment: In this case you can save it in BDD

Comment: I'm unsure what BDD is, I'll look into it though!

Comment: Do you have a link I could read off of to try to get a grasp of BDD?

Comment: Hum... Sorry right name of BDD is database. You can use some database and manipulate it using PDO. [Tutorial Here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Comment: You have to install a database. MySQL is the easier IMO.

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually working in an environment where I have access to databases. The problem is I am having trouble getting my code to communicate with them - it keeps error'ing out on me, which makes me believe that the admin may have shut down the ability to communicate between server and database unless I have admin rights. Although it could just be my code.